# Hebrew characters looks garbled (Java+Objectify+JSP)

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine

I have a HTML form

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"
    action="<%=blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/nonameyet")%>"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name=name /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name=price /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name=quantity /></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="image" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="add" /></td>
        </tr>
```

after sending the data I receive it here:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
    List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("image");

    if (blobKeys.get(0) == null) {
     resp.sendRedirect("/");
    }
    req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    BlobKey blobKey = blobKeys.get(0);
    Product product = new Product();
    String name = req.getParameter("name");

    String priceAsString = req.getParameter("price");
    int price = Integer.parseInt(priceAsString);

    String quantityAsString = req.getParameter("quantity");
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityAsString);

    product.setName(name);
    product.setPrice(price);
    product.setQuantity(quantity);
    String url = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey));
    product.setImage(url);
    ofy().save().entities(product).now();
    resp.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");
}
```

and now the JSP is:

```
        <%
            List<Product> list = ofy().load().type(Product.class).limit(20)
                    .list();
            for (Product product : list) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=product.getName()%></td>
            <td><%=product.getPrice()%></td>
            <td><%=product.getQuantity()%></td>
            <td><img alt="<%=product.getName()%>"
                src="<%=product.getImage()%>" width="100" height="100" /></td>
            <td><a
                href="/delete-product?id=<%=product.getId().toString()%>">delete</a>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
```

But when I view the page in Chrome it looks like this:
[image: garbled characters]

After examining the data in http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/datastore, I can see the word in Hebrew is correct:
[image: in the datastore]
So I get to the conclusion that somewhere on the way from the datastore to the jsp the text gets garbled. Can someone help?

Comment: What is the Content-type set by the JSP?

Comment: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Comment: Can you check what `req.getCharacterEncoding()` returns *right on the first line of the servlet*? Before you call `setCharecterEncoding()`?

Comment: But I can see in the admin console that it is written in the right way, and in the view page code it is set to utf-8

Comment: I think you should try and move the `setCharacterEncoding()` to be the first call in your servlet, *before* reading the images. Can you check if this works?

Comment: 3 things could go wrong: (1) encoding in `req` is bad and name is already saved with bad encoding (despite the fact that you see it in admin). To check this, get the actual bytes (`name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)`). (2) object not properly reconstructed by Objectify. To see this, do the same on `product.getName()` in the JSP. (3) The JSP does not send the correct character encoding (check in browser).